# Storing strings in array as user selects checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I just started using `angularJS` and am trying to learn how to insert strings in array when user clicks checkbox and later access these values.

This is what I have so far:

```
<md-button class="toolbar-button" ng-click="removePlan()">
    <md-icon>delete</md-icon>
</md-button>    
<md-list-item ng-repeat="plan in plans">
        <md-checkbox ng-model="plansSelected[plan._id]"> </md-checkbox>
    </md-list-item>
```

apps.js

```
$scope.plansSelected = []
$scope.removePlan = function () {
   for (var plan in $scope.plansSelected) {
      if ($scope.plansSelected[plan] === true) {
          projectResource.removePlan(plan).then(function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
              $scope.plans.push(data.plan)
            }
          })
      }
   }
}
```

projectResource.js

```
resource.removePlan = function (planId) {
     return $http.delete(getPlanUrl(planId)).then(processResponse, processError)
} 

function getPlansUrl () {
    return getProjectUrl() + '/plans'
  }

  function getPlanUrl () {
    return getPlansUrl() + '/' + $route.current.params.planId
  }
```

In debugger this is how my array looks like:

```
$scope.plansSelected: Array[0]
57bd40128a58022800887d80:false
57bd40328a58022800887d88:false
57cc2bcbb452140500b0334a:false
```

I am checking if user removed selection from the checkbox and if the value is true then take that plan._id and pass in the loop to `removePlan` function.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong, because this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be more specific what "this is not working" means - it's hard for us to detect that without being able to run it.

I can see that your use of $scope.plansSelected as an empty array is wrong. I would dispense with that and do it like this:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="plan in plans track by $index">
    {{plan.name}} <md-checkbox ng-model="plans[$index].selected"> </md-checkbox>
</md-list-item>
```

This basically adds a 'selected' attribute to your plans array, and make it easier for you to iterate over the plans array and pull out the ones you want.